# Convert numeric to date format in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Assume I am reading in a csv / text file into Tableau.  I have a variable that contains years (yyyy).  How do I convert this into an actual year in Tableau?  I have tried.  So, assume my data look like:

```
YEAR
2001
2002
2002
2001
2002
2004
```

I have tried `DATEPARSE("yyyy", "YEAR")` but this returns:  `1/1/00 12:00:00 AM`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new calculated field with this as the formula:

DATEPARSE("yyyy", [YEAR])

The brackets around YEAR indicate that it is a field.  Quotation marks (like you have) indicate that it is a hard-coded string.

Comment: Thanks!  I had to convert to string (STR) and then parse the date (DATEPARSE).  Much appreciated -- this was my missing link.

Comment: Instead of calling STR(), you can change the data type of YEAR to a string, by right clicking on the field and setting the type. Could be more efficient than converting to a string in the calculation, but probably not a big deal in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient alternative is to call makedate(YEAR, 1, 1), assuming that the field YEAR is an integer. This avoids any string conversions

Comment: MAKEdate is not available while using Live Data Extracts, but would be ok for a csv source.